# Accessing string sub elements in a multidimensional javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

How can I access the "case" and "note" values for each "time" key value in the below code?

Have I made an error in defining my object?

```js
obj = {
 "1483805300000": [{"case":"77222","note":"Hello"}],
 "1483805600000": [{"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}]
};

for (const prop in obj) {
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop.case +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop["note"] +'<br>');
}
```

```css
div{background:beige;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Also tried this:

```js
obj = {
 "1483805300000": {"case":"77222","note":"Hello"},
 "1483805600000": {"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}
};

for (const prop in obj) {
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop.case +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop["note"] +'<br>');
}
```

```css
div{background:beige;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

And yup, Charlie's suggestion in comments also works:

```js
obj = {
 "1483805300000": {"case":"77222","note":"Hello"},
 "1483805600000": {"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}
};

for (const prop in obj) {
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop].case +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop]["note"] +'<br>');
}
```

```css
div{background:beige;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: why the array wrapping each individual object?

Comment: Cause I don't know what I'm doing : )

Comment: Well, will there be more than one for each time value?

Comment: Is the case/note object always the first item in the array?

Comment: @charlietfl Nope, just the one. I tried it without the square brackets and that didn't work either. *After dozens of attempts its difficult to filter all attempted combinations down to one sample for the question.*

Comment: Is requirement to concatenate `.innerHTML` of `div` with properties of objects in array?

Comment: missed referencing the `obj[prop].propertyName` ..my bad. remove the `[]` and use that syntax

Comment: @charlietfl Right you be. Please add that (just glom the 3rd code sample from my question - it's *your* solution) as an answer so I can upvote and ultimately choose a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the array wrapping each individual object and use `obj[prop].propertyName` or `obj[prop]['propertyName']` to access appropriate property values

```js
obj = {
 "1483805300000": {"case":"77222","note":"Hello"},
 "1483805600000": {"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}
};

for (var prop in obj) {
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop].case +'<br>');
  $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop]["note"] +'<br>');
}
```

```css
div{background:beige;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: @charlietfl Is calling `jQuery()` and `.html()` six times each at each iteration necessary?

Comment: @guest271314 good point, was more focused on how to structure and access the objects. Pretty sure OP can clean that up

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.each()`, `.append()`

```js
const obj = {
 "1483805300000": [{"case":"77222","note":"Hello"}],
 "1483805600000": [{"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}]
};

let div = $("div");

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  div.append(`${key}<br>${value[0]["case"]}<br>${value[0]["note"]}<br><br>`
  )
})
```

```css
div{background:beige;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">    
</script>

<div></div>
```

Alternatively, using `Object.keys()`, `.map()` to iterate objects within array

```js
const obj = {
 "1483805300000": [{"case":"77222","note":"Hello"}],
 "1483805600000": [{"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}]
};

let div = $("div");

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  div.append(`${key}
              <br>
              ${Object.keys(value[0]).map(function(prop) {
                return `${value[0][prop]}<br>` 
                }).concat("<br>").join("")
              }`
  )
})
```

```css
div{background:beige;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">    
</script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: The `function` doesn't seem necessary. Can't you append the value directly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `obj[prop][0].case` & `obj[prop][0].note` instead of `prop.case` & `prop['note']` like following.

```js
obj = {
    "1483805300000": [{"case":"77222","note":"Hello"}],
    "1483805600000": [{"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}]
};

for (const prop in obj) {
    $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop +'<br>');
    $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop][0].case +'<br>');
    $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop][0].note +'<br>');
}
```

```css
div {
    background: beige;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

If you don't use the arrays (brackets []) then you need to use  `obj[prop].case` &  `obj[prop].note`

```js
obj = {
    "1483805300000": {"case":"77222","note":"Hello"},
    "1483805600000": {"case":"77333","note":"Hello 333"}
};

for (const prop in obj) {
    $('div').html( $('div').html() + prop +'<br>');
    $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop].case +'<br>');
    $('div').html( $('div').html() + obj[prop].note +'<br>');
}
```

```css
div{
    background: beige;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `obj[prop][0]`...

```js
obj = {
  "1483805300000": [{
    "case": "77222",
    "note": "Hello"
  }],
  "1483805600000": [{
    "case": "77333",
    "note": "Hello 333"
  }]
};

for (const prop in obj) {

  $('div').html($('div').html() + prop + '<br>');
  $('div').html($('div').html() + obj[prop][0].case+'<br>');
  $('div').html($('div').html() + obj[prop][0].note + '<br>');
}
```

```css
div {
  background: beige;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```